# Backtrace and console writes with MPI out of order

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran

I am experiencing an odd behaviour running a Fortran application with MPI and `gfortran`. Consider the following code:

```
write(*,*) "Start"
call backtrace ()
write(*,*) "End"
```

If I compile and run the code with `gfortran`, everything goes as expected, this is, the code prints "Start", followed by the backtrace and last by "End". However, if I compile this with `mpifort` and run with `mpiexec`, even though I ensure that only one process is running this sequence, the output is unpredictable. Sometimes the code outputs as expected, sometimes it prints "Start", "End" and then the backtrace, and can even fall in the case where it prints something in the middle of the backtrace.

Below you can find a minimal working example (`test.f90`) that reproduces this behaviour. The code can be compiled with

```
mpifort -g -cpp -DMPI test.f90 -o a.out
```

and executed with

```
mpirun -n 2 ./a.out
```

test.f90

```
module mod

private
public sub1

contains

subroutine sub1
call sub2
end subroutine sub1

subroutine sub2
call sub3
end subroutine sub2

subroutine sub3
call sub4
end subroutine sub3

subroutine sub4
call sub5
end subroutine sub4

subroutine sub5
call sub6
end subroutine sub5

subroutine sub6
call sub7
end subroutine sub6

subroutine sub7
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : error_unit, output_unit
#ifdef MPI
use mpi
integer :: i, n, e
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, n, e)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, i, e)
write(output_unit,*) "From ", i , " / ", n
#endif
flush (output_unit)
flush (error_unit)
write(*,*) "Start"
flush (output_unit)
call backtrace ()
flush (error_unit)
write(*,*) "End"
flush (output_unit)
end subroutine sub7

end module mod



program test

use mod
#ifdef MPI
use mpi
#endif

implicit none

integer :: i, n, e

#ifdef MPI
call mpi_init(e)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, n, e)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, i, e)
if (i == 0) call sub1
call mpi_finalize(e)
#else
call sub1
#endif

end program test
```

One output:

```
 From            0  /            2
 Start
#0  0x7f0b9db05d21 in ???
#1  0x55b1dc9cc3f7 in sub7
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:45
#2  0x55b1dc9cc4de in sub6
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:29
#3  0x55b1dc9cc4ea in sub5
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:25
#4  0x55b1dc9cc4f6 in sub4
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:21
#5  0x55b1dc9cc502 in sub3
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:17
#6  0x55b1dc9cc50e in sub2
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:13
#7  0x55b1dc9cc51a in __mod_MOD_sub1
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:9
 End
#8  0x55b1dc9cc56b in test
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:70
#9  0x55b1dc9cc5b0 in main
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:57
```

Another output:

```
 From            0  /            2
 Start
 End
#0  0x7f23ae8b8d21 in ???
#1  0x557937a503f7 in sub7
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:45
#2  0x557937a504de in sub6
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:29
#3  0x557937a504ea in sub5
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:25
#4  0x557937a504f6 in sub4
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:21
#5  0x557937a50502 in sub3
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:17
#6  0x557937a5050e in sub2
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:13
#7  0x557937a5051a in __mod_MOD_sub1
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:9
#8  0x557937a5056b in test
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:70
#9  0x557937a505b0 in main
    at /home/amcc/mwe/backtrace/test.f90:57
```

Any hints on ensuring that the output is written correctly?

Versions:
Output of `mpifort --show`

```
f95 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/mpich -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/mpich -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmpichfort -lmpich
```

Output of `mpifort --version`

```
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
```

Comment: I faced a similar issue long time ago and the root cause was Fortran and C use different buffers that are flushed independently, and hence the overlap. An other possible explanation is `write()` writes to `stdout` and `backtrace()` writes to `stderr` and `mpiexec` overlaps both.

Comment: Your first comment is very enlightening and really helps me understand such behaviour. I feel it is not related with the standard output stream, since it never happens when running without MPI. Did you find another workaround for this?

Comment: `gfortran` doc states `backtrace()` writes to `error_unit` but your program `write()` to `output_unit`, so I guess the interleaving comes from `mpiexec`. In `C`, I would try to `dup2(2,1)` so `stderr` is redirected to `stdout` at the MPI task level (e.g. before it reaches `mpiexec`), and since you always `flush()` that **might** do the trick. Not sure if Fortran has a `dup2()` like subroutine ... if not,  you have to implement it in `C` and call it at the very beginning of your MPI program.